# How do I raise team morale in solo queue?

Tags: league-of-legends

I frequently find that members of my team in solo queue give up after being counter picked, after losing first blood, after losing the first team fight, etc.

I am not one to rage or get mad while playing a fun game, and I tend to stay optimistic. There are always comebacks and no game is over till your nexus is gone. Why do some people not understand this, and just give up?

I've already watched a few teams in the ggchronicle have comebacks, I don't understand why people don't believe they can happen in solo queue, which is such a dodgy place.

Tl;dr? In conclusion, How do you get your team to stay positive and keep trying?

Comment: Hi @Bunny, your question was closed as Not Constructive because it's a very subjective question likely to only solicit opinions as answers. We're a Q&A site that focuses on concrete problemsolving, and while your question *is* a problem for you, there is no definitive answer that can be accepted for it. This would fit better on a discussion forum, as our Q&A engine is ill-suited for these types of questions.

Answer (score 2):

Not much you can do except talk to them, stay positive and just keep throwing in some " We can still do this, just take a deep breath and focus up again "

But i agree this happends way to often in solo queue's

Answer (score 1):

The thing is about solo queue is that all players have experience about trollers, feeders, and such and seeing first blood on your team is a downer because you get this feeling of a feeder is on your team. Try to dominate your lane and get some kills to encourage that they stand a chance. Destroy the enemy turret do something to get your team ahead even temporarily.

The safest way to get a comeback is to team up early and move together and do seek-and-destroy. That means you get all 5 champions together and go kill 1 or 2 champions at a time who are in a lane by themselves. You can get assists for everyone some gold and push the turrets as well. The danger is that the other team pushes hard and gets turrets on your however. But the risk is worth it at times

Answer (score 1):

You have to be the one to try and talk to everyone. However, there are ignorant people who will just flame back at you for no apparent reason. You just have to try always stay positive point out why your team can win. Tell them what to do if you have to. You just have to try.

Answer (score 1):

Always be polite even if some of your team mates might be dicks...try to get their mindset on winning and never surrender try to reach out to them don't let them give up always say no to surrenders.

Answer (score 0):

:) I just try being nice and/or cracking jokes. Praise good plays by your teammates, laugh off bad luck. It's really the small things that add up. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>e</kbd> (only applies when you play gangplank).

Answer (score 0):

In chat be positive and joke around with your team. NEVER be negative because it is contagious and people lose their will to win.

Your comments do have an affect on your W/L ratio so take them seriously.

Answer (score 0):

Good communication which may be hard, but a simple greeting in champion select when you first see who is going to be on you team goes a long way in setting up the right frame of mind.  If you are lucky, you'll even get a team that will say and coordinate what role each will play.  Stay positive and lead with your words in game chat.  For example if your mid swain gets destroyed by a leblanc.  You could say A) "/all Swain is feeder.  Report pls" or B) "/all leblanc op, nerf now!", you may think it's obvious the answer would be B.  But really, it's C) "Don't worry team, leblanc falls off late game, just get lots of magic resist and kill off the rest of her team in teamfights." or something to that effect.